# Hosting a mvc app via IIS with windows authentication, but I get IIS APPPOOL\ APP I need the windows user that connects (works with IIS express)

Tags: c#, iis, windows-authentication, iis-express

I saw similar questions like this on here but I simply can't find a good solution.

My problem:
I have an app that need to retrieve data from a connection string, and information that is retrieved depends on the authenticated windows user. When I run this in dev environment with IIS Express I get my logged in user.

However when I host it via IIS Local i get ( IIS APPPOOL\ ) as the user. I need this to be the windows user.

Even tho I get the login the application still outputs APPPOOL when I check this in my views

Anyone with a good solution to this?

I tried:

```
  @System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
  @System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
  @HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name

<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <trace enabled="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Basic knowledge you should learn first, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You should use the User property of Page class or Controller class. The three you listed above are not usually the ones you should use.

Comment: Hi, thanks, great information. However the Page class didn't seem to work either still gets the IIS APPPOL/APP as identity.

Comment: Then you probably enabled IIS anonymous authentication, and also used pool identity as anonymous account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your application are always imepersonate as application pool identity.

I can get the correct windows identity via

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

 HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name

User.Identity.Name;
```

First of all, please ensure your authentication looks like this. Please disable **impersonate** and **anonymous** at the same time.

```
<location path="mysite">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
```

Secondly,please promise  your windows authentication are not executed with app pool credential
[image]

Finally, you should get the correct credential.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but It still didn't work, already had that false. The application is saying IIS APPPOOL/APP on all my user.identity.name and so on. Also on page class.unfortunally. Is there other configurations that needs to be done? Or is there someting Im missing?  I had disabled everything except windows auth. identity impersonate i tried both on and off.

Comment: @Vidar Have you tried to set app pool's setting Load user profile to true and refresh the application pool? Besides, have you cleaned browser cache after changing these configuration?

Comment: Yes, it is set to true and I recycle app pool, also restarted site and tried in an incognito mode. If i run this on a new mvc app with local IIS i get the same problem. If only I could get it to work similar to IIS express

Comment: @Vidarv Its weird that all apis return the same "IIS APPPOOL" result. At least one api should get the correct username. Could you see the login user name in your IIS log?  Besides, did you input username and password manually in web browser? Or you are using automatic sign-in?

Comment: Just looked and I see my username in the IIS log, atm I put it in manually in the web browser.

Comment: Tested a new application and pre-selected windows authentication and now I atleast get the user. Which is good progress :).

Comment: Hi Are you using pass-through authentication in your basic setting?

Comment: Hi, it seems that windows authentication now works and I get the right user. It worked since I created a new application with this preselected. Thanks for the help anyways!